# Installing firebase in vue 3 - no files created

Tags: firebase, vuejs3

I come from vue 2 and when I installed firebase to vue 2 i just typed "npm install firebase" and firebase did the magic in the background and created all the files needed e.g. for hosting, security rules etc. But with Vue 3, when I try to install firebase by typing "npm install firebase", no fire is created.

Do I do something wrong or does a working work around for this problem exist?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What files are you referring to? Also `npm install firebase` just installs the Firebase SDK and adds it to `package.json` as a dependency. Are you referring to `firebase init` command that generates all necessary files for selected services such as functions and security rules?

Comment: Hello, I refer e.g. to files like firebase,json, firestore.rules etc. It depends which setup you choose after you enter firebase init. I tried it now several times but these files were not generated automatically. I created them now manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the files now manually. It depends on the setup you need. Since I use hosting and the firebase database I created the following files:

*** (in the root folder) .firebaserc (you can find your project id in your project settings in your firebase project)**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "your-project-id"
  }
}
```

*** (in the root folder) firebase.json**

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "trailingSlash": false, 
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please be aware that the second source code describes the following:

- the file for the firestore rules is: firestore.rules
- the file for the indexes is: firestore.indexes.json
- there are no trailing slashed in the URL
- the public folder is (not public): **dist**
- this config is for a single page application